# TextBox.TextChanged and "CTRL-a"

Tags: c#, winforms

I write simply code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test01
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 32);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.textBox1.Text = "Text";
            this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
            // 
            // checkBox1
            // 
            this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
            this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(38, 65);
            this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
            this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 17);
            this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.checkBox1.Text = "checkBox1";
            this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(234, 86);
            this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.checkBox1.Checked)
                this.checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            else
                this.checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
    }
}
```

And:

```
namespace Test01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I get a windows with textbox("Text") and checkbox. When i focus on textbox and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> checkbox toggle state, because TextBox.TextChanged raised and textBox1_TextChanged executed.
But, i can`t understand why TextChanged event raised on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>?

Comment: I did notice that it doesn't happen if the text is already selected, so could be to do with selection of the text rather than the key combination.

Comment: @JustinHarvey Yes it doesn`t happen if the text is already selected and I press ctrl-a. It doesn`t happen when I select text with mouse or with context menu, also. But, I can`t find explanation.

Comment: I tried debugging a bit, looks like the textbox receives exactly the same message as when text is typed (`WM_USER wparam:0300075C lParam:0006075C`). So the behavior seems 'normal' on .NET side, and should be similar with a C/C++ app. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the Windows API to dig any further...

Comment: The event is triggered by the EN_CHANGE notification.  The SDK says: "Sent when the user has taken an action that **may** have altered text".  No promises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I met the same problem, use this code below:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (textBox1.SelectedText == textBox1.Text && textBox1.Text != "")
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress this behaviour by adding the condition below:

```
    void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
            return;

        //rest of the code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for my problem:

```
void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (_oldText.Equals(this.textBox1.Text))
        return;
    _oldText = this.textBox1.Text;
    //rest of code
}
```

I can`t find better solution.